# How can i get rid of hard coding in creating a new EntityKey in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5

How can i get rid of hard coding in creating a new EntityKey in Entity Framework

Answer (score 2):

```
GetType(Model).Name
GetType(Account).Name
```

which means:

```
Public Shared Function GetName(Of TEntity As Type)() As String
    Dim type = GetType(TEntity)
    If Not type.IsSubclassOf(GetType(EntityObject)) Then Throw New Exception("Item must inherit from EntityObject.")
    Return GetType(ObjectContextName).Name & "." & type.Name
End Function
```

If you pluralizaed your entity-sets in .NET 3.5 (which Pluralization Service doesn't exist), use:

```
private static string ObjectContextName = typeof(Rlp.Data.Entities).Name;
public static string GetEntityName<TEntity>([Optional, DefaultParameterValue(false)]bool pluralize) where TEntity : Type
{
    Type type = typeof(TEntity);
    if (!type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityObject))) throw new Exception("Item must inherit from EntityObject.");
    string entitySet = type.Name;
    if (pluralize) entitySet = Pluralizer.ToPlural(entitySet);
    return ObjectContextName + "." + entitySet;
}
```

Or even:

```
private static string ObjectContextName = typeof(Rlp.Data.Entities).Name;
private const string EntityIdSuffix = "Id";
public static EntityKey CreateEntityKey<TEntity>(string id , [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(false)]bool pluralize) where TEntity : Type
{
    Type type = typeof(TEntity);
    if (!type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityObject))) throw new Exception("Item must inherit from EntityObject.");
    string entity = type.Name;
    string entitySet;
    entitySet = pluralize? Pluralizer.ToPlural(entity): entity;
    return new EntityKey(ObjectContextName + "." + entitySet, entity + EntityIdSuffix, id);  
}
```

**The Pluralizer helper is from: [Simple English Noun Pluralizer in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2007/01/11/simple-english-noun-pluralizer-in-c.aspx)**